# Is there a way to lock a comboBox PyQt?

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt5

I'm currently working on a GUI and I want to lock a combo box until a radio button is activated.
I read the functions existing in this link : https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QComboBox.html but I havn't found anything yet.

here is a screen of what I already made :
[image]

basically what I want : We can't select anything in the two combo boxes until we checked "Jusqu'au ... :"

EDIT :
Here is what I already wrote :

```py
class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        '''
        some code 
        '''
        self.totalChronique.clicked.connect(self.lock_comboBoxes) #the button "toute la chronique"
        self.selectTime.clicked.connect(self.unlock_comboBoxes) #the button "Jusqu'au ..." 

    def unlock_comboBoxes(self): 
        self.comboDay.setEnabled(True) #the combo box "jours" 
        self.comboMonth.setEnabled(True) #the combo box "mois" 
    def lock_comboBoxes(self):
        self.comboDay.setEnabled(False)
        self.comboMonth.setEnabled(False)
```

Thanks for yours tips

Comment: Can't you just use `setEnabled(False)`?

Comment: I already tried but it didn't work

Comment: nevermind, I did it it doesn't work, I wrote it again it worked, I guess I just writed it wrong .. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

using setEnabled(False) worked just fine